# Nested tag with text and variable are not interpreted

Tags: thymeleaf

I have nested tag

today is not interpreted

```
<p th:text="#{today}">  <span th:text="${today}">16 december 2021</span> </p>
```

With this line, that work but that don't get the same output

```
<p th:text="#{today}"> </p> <span th:text="${today}">16 december 2021</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<p>
  [[#{today}]]
  <span th:text="${today}">16 december 2021</span>
</p>
```

or

```
<p>
  <span th:text="#{today}" />
  <span th:text="${today}">16 december 2021</span>
</p>
```

Outer tags overwrite their contents, so just move the outer text in.

Comment: is there any particular reason about the outer tags overwrite the other? don't see it in the doc

Comment: That's just the way it works... the closest I can get to something stating it is this from the doc: `The th:text attribute, which evaluates its value expression and sets the result as the body of the host tag, effectively replacing the “Welcome to our grocery store!” text we see in the code.`